# Razor not creating shared folder for views automatically? Why not?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I am following this tutorial...

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-3

Apparently Razor will create the shared folder in views automatically and create a _ViewStart.cshtml file... it doesn't.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably used the empty project template. Mentioned files are created in the other templates.

Comment: Really?!.. what an odd tutorial... it tells you to use an empty one... then tells you that the files are created automatically a few pages later... I am baffled.

Comment: @Slippy That's right I guess. You may also want to create an Internet application check it out first, you need some configuration for Razor.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to use empty as I don't want loads of random crap in my project... do you know what I need to configure to add razor to the project?

Comment: @Slippy I added configuration sections from an ASP.NET MVC 4 template.

Comment: Thanks for the much needed help! I am sure this will help, and I am sorry but I have just one more question... where do I put that configuration? web.config?

Comment: @Slippy wait a sec. I am checking the default template. Are you using MVC 3 or 4?

Comment: I am using MVC 4, I opened an internet application project to try and help out with how to configure razor in my empty project... but I have no idea...

Comment: @Slippy Looks like empty project adds the configuration for Razor. See the Web.config inside Views folder. You can try to copy the  _ViewStart.cshtml and _Layout.cshtml and see it's working.

Comment: Yeah, I see the code you posted in my web.config file there already... I can create the files manually, but only if I create a simple hello world type page... if I use the one from a sample project such as "Internet application", there are other things being depended on such as the code which imports all the css in the content folder etc. Razor doesn't seem to do any of that in MVC 4.

Comment: @Slippy Nope. You don't get any CSS or JavaScript files in empty template. You can copy what you need from Internet template or use NuGet. Also you don't get bundling in empty template either.

Answer (score 10):

ASP MVC beginner here, so I may be wrong.

I think the problem comes from the fact that the tutorial is written for ASP MVC 3 and you're probably using MVC 4, which has more project template options when you create a new ASP MVC project.

If you choose "Empty" as your project template, nothing is created in the Views folder and you're stuck when you create a new view in the tutorial.
If you choose "Basic" (apparently added in MVC 4), the Views folder contains a Shared subfolder and the default config files used in the tutorial.

Hope it helps !

Comment: it solve the problem perfectly +1, should marked as best answer